# How do I add multiple classes to a Generic ArrayList?

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I'm doing an assignment where I can only add specific classes to a generic ArrayList, but the ArrayList does not seem to be adding the classes as intended.

```
public class ComputerOrder<T extends Product> extends GenericOrder<T> {
private List<T> products;//the list of items

    public void addProduct(T t) {
        if (t.getClass().isInstance(ComputerPart.class)) {
            products.add(t);    
        }
        if (t.getClass().isInstance(Service.class)) {
            products.add(t);   
        }
        if (t.getClass().isInstance(Peripheral.class)) {
            products.add(t);   
        }
        else System.out.println("Not the right type of object.");
   }
```

---

Main args test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ComputerPart c;
    c = new ComputerPart(12);

    ComputerOrder<Product> g3 = new ComputerOrder<>();
    g3.addProduct(c);
    g3.print();

}
```

The expected result would be that ArrayList g3 would be able to add c, since it's an instance of a ComputerPart object, but instead the ArrayList is empty. Could someone explain what I am doing wrong with my code?

Note: that "else" statement is only in there for testing purposes, and seems to indicate that the if statements are not working correctly, since it keeps getting triggered when I test.

Comment: The println will be triggered too often since you haven't used `else if` for the Service and Peripheral checks. But that won't solve the main problem. Try adding printlns in each conditional clause to help figure out what's going on.

Comment: Even with the `isInstance` fixed, this is a terrible way to work with generics or object-oriented programming in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primary problem is that you've messed up your isinstance check. That method works in reverse; what you're looking for is:

`ComputerPart.class.isInstance(t)`, not `t.getClass().isInstance(ComputerPart.class)`. But, you can write this a lot more simply as: `t instanceof ComputerPart`.

Secondarily you've messed up the sysout. Presumably you meant for each 'if' in your code to be an 'else if' instead, except for the first one of course.

Comment: Thanks very much, rzwitserloot, the t instanceof ... works. I appreciate the help!